# Dick has 5 loaves of bread. Nick has 3 loaves. The three share the bread equally with Albert. Albert gives Dick and Nick $8. What's a fair split?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Dick and Nick share their food with Albert. Dick has 5 loaves of bread and Nick has 3 loaves. The three share the bread equally. Albert gives Dick and Nick 8 dollars, which they agree to share fairly.
How should Dick and Nick divide the eight dollars between them?

Dicks contributes $5/8$ of the loaves, while Nick contributes $3/8$. They each get $8/3$ of the bread.
Dick provided $5/8$ of Albert's meal so he should get \$5 and Nick \$3. Is that correct?
I'm not completely sure. It sort of feels right but not quite intuitively. I'm imagining the 8 loaves of bread combined into one. Split equally the bread still contains $5/8$ bread from Dick...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: That can't be right.

Comment: The answers below are correct but I must warn you that if your teacher is "woke" the answer is four dollars each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick answer.

There are 8 total loaves. Make them equal 24 pieces ( That means each bread has three slices). Albert eats 8 of them and gave them 8 bucks. That means each piece is worth 1$.

Since Dick had 15 slices of pieces of bread, he deserves 7 bucks, and the other guy deserves 1 buck. Note that Albert eats 7 slices from Dick's share and 1 slice from Nick's share.

Do you understand why?

Comment: Yes. That certainly clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Dick gets 7\$ and Nick gets 1\$. Here's why. Dick brought 5 loaves of bread, but ate $\frac83$ of them. Therefore, he gave $\frac73$ to Albert. On the other hand, Nick brought 3 loaves of bread, but ate $\frac83$ of them. Therefore, he gave $\frac13$ to Albert. So, Dick gave Albert $7$ times more loaves of bread, and therefore he deserves to get $7$ times more money.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not right. Imagine that before Albert arrives, Dick and Nick each eat $\frac83$ loaves. Then Dick is left with $\frac73$ loaves and Nick is left with $\frac17$. So Dick should get $7$ of Albert's dollars.

Answer (score 0):

> Dick contributes $5/8$ of the loaves, while Nick contributes $3/8$.

This sounds intuitive but it is false. The question says they get $8/3$ loaves each.

Answer (score 0):

Albert:  $8\$$ in exchange of  $\frac{8}{3}$ loaves of bread $\to$ ~3$/bread.

Dick: ($5-\frac{8}{3}) =\frac{7}{3}$  bread $\cdot 3 \$/bread= 7$\$

Nick: ($3-\frac{8}{3}) =\frac{1}{3}$bread $\cdot\$/bread 3 = 1$\$

Answer (score 0):

So $\$8$ for $\frac 83$ loaves of bread seems fair. SO $\$ 1$ for $\frac 13$ of a loaf.

So Albert needs to pay Dick $5$ dollars and Nick $3$ dollars.  FIne, but what do Nick and Dick need to pay? Nick ate Dicks bread so Nick owes Dick something.  But instead of paying Dick directly Nick is just going to let Nick take some of Dick's share from Albert.

Each person ate $\frac 83$ loaves of bread so the should all come out $8$ dollars poorer either in bread the gave or money the paid for.

Albert contributed no bread at all so he pays entirely in dollars.  $\$8$ .

Dick contributed $3$ loaves or an $9$ dollars worth of bread. So he has already paid $\$9$ in bread.  But he ate $8$ dollars worth.  SO he is owed $\$1$ which he'll take in cash from Albert.

Nick contributed $5$ loaves or $\$15$ worth of bread. He ate $\$8$ worth.  So he is owed $\$7$ which he takes from Albert.

There are many ways of looking at this.

I:  Nick has $5$ loaves of bread.  He eats $\frac 83$ of them and gives the remaining $\frac 73$ to Albert. Dick has $3$ loaves of bread.  He eats $\frac 83$ of them and gives the remaining $\frac 13$ to Albert.  ALbert recieves $\frac 83$ loaves of bread and pays $8$ dollars for them.

II:  Albert ate $8$ portions of Bread.  He figures $5$ of them came from Dick so he gives Dick $5$ dollars, and $3$ of them came from Nick so he gives Nick $3$ dollars.  Nick ate $8$ portions of Bread and figure $5$ of them came from him so he pays himself $5$ dollars, and $3$ comes from Nick so he pays Nick $3$ dollars.  And Nick does the same; he pays Dick $5$ dollars and pays himself $3$ dollars.

So in the end: Dick has $5 + 5+ 5 - 3-5 = +7$ dollars.  And Nick has $3+3+3-5 -3 = +1$ and Albert has $-5-3=-8$.

III:  Everyone puts what they've got in a pot and takes back stuff of equal value.

Nick puts in $\$15$ worth of bread.  Dick puts in $\$9$ worth of bread.  Albert puts in $\$8$.

Nick takes back $\$8$ worth of bread and $\$7$ cash.  Dick takes out $\$8$ worth of bread and $\$1$.  Albert takes back $\$8$ worth of bread.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not well-specified. For one thing, most of the answers assume that the worth of a loaf of bread is determined by what Albert donates. But actually, Dick and Nick both bought their bread before Albert arrived, and the price was determined by the baker, not by Albert. If the aim is to treat Dick and Nick fairly, one could argue that this needs to be done in two stages. First, ensure that neither Dick or Nick suffers financially as a result of their unequal contributions to the shared meal. Then, ensure that whatever additional money they receive from Albert is divided equally between Dick and Nick. Here are a few possible scenarios:

(a) One loaf costs 10 cents. If Albert hadn't come along, Nick would have given Dick $((50-30)÷2) = 10$ cents to make it fair. Because Albert did come along, they now have an extra \$8 to share, so Dick should receive $((8÷2)+0.10) = \$4.10$, and Nick should receive $((8÷2)-0.10) = \$3.90$.

(b) One loaf costs $\$1$. If Albert hadn't come along, Nick would have given Dick $((5-3)÷2) = \$1$ to make it fair. Because Albert did come along, they now have an extra $\$8$ to share, so Dick should receive $((8÷2)+1) = \$5$, and Nick should receive $((8÷2)-1) = \$3$.

(c) One loaf costs \$3. If Albert hadn't come along, Nick would have given Dick $((15-9)÷2) = \$3$ to make it fair. Because Albert did come along, they now have an extra $\$8$ to share, so Dick should receive $((8÷2)+3) = \$7$, and Nick should receive $((8÷2)-3) = \$1$.

(d) One loaf costs \$4. If Albert hadn't come along, Nick would have given Dick $((20-12)÷2) = \$4$ to make it fair. Because Albert did come along, they now have an extra \$8 to share, so Dick should receive $((8÷2)+4) = \$8$, and Nick should receive $((8÷2)-4) = \$0$.

If a loaf costs any more than $4, then Dick should receive all the money, and Nick will still be in his debt.

Of course, this is just one way of defining fairness. Beware of being entranced by numbers and plunging into calculations, before you have specified what the problem actually means.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer is hard to read. I tried typing it several times, but it kept coming out like that. My point was that all the other answers make unjustified assumptions about how much money Dick and Nick should be compensated. Suppose Albert had donated 8 million dollars. Would you then say that obviously a loaf of bread must be worth 3 million dollars, so Dick deserves to get 7 million and Nick only deserves to get 1 million?

Comment: Thanks to Moo for editing my post to make it more readable.